# How to load JavaScript enabled response using axios or fetch API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, http, browser, axios

I am working on a personal project in which I want to read the whole HTML of a JavaScript dependent webpage. For Example if I to load [this URL](https://www.instagram.com/p/CARPYLZgFFv/) in a JavaScript Enabled web browser, this is what I get:

[image: An Image Post on Instagram]

However, if I disable JavaScript in the browser, and load [the same URL](https://www.instagram.com/p/CARPYLZgFFv/) now, I get this:

[image: Only the Instagram LOGO]

This is pretty normal I know.

---

Now I am trying to load the HTML of [the same link](https://www.instagram.com/p/CARPYLZgFFv/) in JavaScript code using axios HTTP client, and obviously I am getting the HTML of JavaScript disabled webpage as the HTTP response.

**I want to get the HTML(+JS) source as the response of [the same link](https://www.instagram.com/p/CARPYLZgFFv/) (in which JavaScript is enabled). I don't know how to mimic a JavaScript enabled Web Browser when working with HTTP clients like axios or fetch API.**

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the browser, or in another environment? If another environment, what environment?

Comment: I am doing this in code using Vanilla JS

Comment: That isn't what I asked. I asked about the environment, not the language.

Comment: I didn't get it? Are you asking about the OS which I use?

Comment: No, I'm asking whether you're doing this in a browser or another environment, such as Node.js, Electron, etc.

Comment: Yes I am trying this in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this in the browser, you basically can't unless the site you're loading lets you do so (via [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) or similar). You'd have to load it into a window or `iframe`, wait for its JavaScript to run, and then access the resulting DOM. But accessing the DOM of a cross-origin page is disabled by default.

The only browser-based way I can think of is to write and install a [browser extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_extension), since when a user installs an extension, they can grant greater power to the extension than a web page normally has.

If you're trying to do this in a non-browser environment, you can use a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) like headless Chromium or similar. The browser-based restrictions don't apply.

Comment: I guess headless browser is what I am seeking. Can you explain about how to use and get started with it. And any comments on 'using Selenium with JS'

Comment: @RohitRawat - I haven't used Selenium. But you've said in a comment you're trying to do this in a browser. The headless browser approach wouldn't work within a browser.

Comment: I understand it @T.J. Crowder. So is window/iframe approach better here?

Comment: @RohitRawat - It would be if it would work. But it won't. As I said above, *"If you're trying to do this in the browser, you basically can't..."* (unless they intentionally let you, via CORS, as mentioned).

Comment: You said in your answer that it can be done if I write an extension. Can you be more specific here please?

Comment: @RohitRawat - I don't see how I can be more specific. I suggest reading up on extensions. Please note the critical part that the extension will only be available to users who install it. So if you want to do what you're describing on the web, it just won't work unless you can get every user to install an extension, which is very unlikely.

Comment: Thank you friend. I will see to it.